# Curvature of a curve proof understanding

Tags: calculus

After the line that says "Using the fact that $T \times T =0$", I don't understand how that fact was used.  How was the equation after that line derived?

[image]

Comment: Hi Al Jebr :) the book from where this page is taken looks cool if you don't mind can you give me its name ?

Comment: https://books.google.ro/books?id=gi3wgIBeBTMC&pg=PA575&lpg=PA575&dq=theorem+10.7.5,+Formula+3&source=bl&ots=mYDDrHQH1_&sig=ACfU3U24ZGD2SRxpwZuImFC4dZ9VTFyauQ&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFi5WGqL_pAhXGqqQKHQkQBP4Q6AEwCHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=theorem%2010.7.5%2C%20Formula%203&f=false

Comment: @the_firehawk James Stewart Calculus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathbf{r}^{'}=\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}\\
\mathbf{r}^{''}=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\mathbf{T}+\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}^{'}$$
 So, 
$$\mathbf{r}^{'}\times\mathbf{r}^{''}=\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}\times\left(\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\mathbf{T}+\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}^{'}\right)=\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}\times\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\mathbf{T}+\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}\times\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}^{'}$$
Since $\mathbf{T}\times\mathbf{T}=0$, this becomes
$$\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}\times\frac{ds}{dt}\mathbf{T}^{'}=\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2\mathbf{T}\times\mathbf{T}^{'}$$

Answer (score 4):

Take the cross product of $\mathbf r''$ with $\mathbf r'$ and distribute.